# How to use Integrator service in Hibernate 5 for adding annotated classes

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jetty, hibernate-5.x

This is with reference to [JPA 2.0: Adding entity classes to PersistenceUnit *from different jar* automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380728/jpa-2-0-adding-entity-classes-to-persistenceunit-from-different-jar-automatic) and [Unable to call Hibernate/QueryDSL from another maven subproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857422/unable-to-call-hibernate-querydsl-from-another-maven-subproject)

It seems that Hibernate 4 had a great way to dynamically load entity classes using 
org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator service.

Now when using Hibernate 5, the Integrator interface's integrate method gives me

```
public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
        SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry)
{

}
```

Where metadata is of type org.hibernate.boot.Metadata

I am unable to call addAnnotatedClass(), neither I am able to obtain the original Configuration object that was there in Hibernate 4.

How do I get around with this?

I am using maven and jetty.

I am not using spring (so please do not provide any spring based solution)

Answer (score 0):

This was actually related to something I was wrestling with over the weekend in getting caught up on Hibernate 5. You can read about the planned changes related to the `Configuration` class in the [latest Javadoc for Hibernate 4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html). The new place for getting info on all loaded entity classes including annotated entities is the `Metadata` class you mentioned. It has a [`getEntityBindings()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/Metadata.html#getEntityBindings--) method that will return the `PersistentClass` entity metadata representation for known all entities. This `Collection` is immutable however.

Recommendation is that you rethink using an `Integrator` to add entity bindings at runtime. This may have worked in the past, but the docs clearly point towards that not being intentional as this should be done at the time of initialization. The `Metadata` and `SessionFactoryImplementor` are for the most part immutable once built, and so the `Integrator`'s intended purpose is not to modify these configuration items but instead use them as information on how to configure new `Service` integrations using the `SessionFactoryServiceRegistry`.

And if you're finding it annoying to configure your `Session` to find all your annotated classes at runtime, I suggest you try using the [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/quickstart/html/#tutorial_jpa) approach for initializing Hibernate as it is far more straightforward and uses standard JPA syntax that can be switched to a handful of other providers if you ever need to. This will automatically scan for annotated entities on your behalf. The API is a bit more simplified and limited, but if you really ever need the power of native Hibernate-specific functionality there is a way to [access the native underlying API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch03.html#d5e1052).